# Работа с Excel в C++

Tags: excel, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь библиотеку *C++* для работы с *Excel* таблицами, или список команд командной строки для этой цели.

Comment: Вам под винду? тогда можно использовать OLE/COM и все делать. Или как то поизворотливее? например, читать оттудова данные и делать все это в FreeBSD в консоли.

Comment: В С++Builder имеются такие видео-компоненты. Правда, сам ни разу не пользовался.

Comment: эммм..видео-компоненты?